# Resign root CA as SUB?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure

Imagine I have a Microsoft root offline ca running since half year, but suddenly I want to include it in my company hierarchy, resigning it with the company official root, But I need both continue running normally, issuing their own crls and all that staff.

I am able to recover private keys from the hsm and move them to the other security world.

Is that even possible? What would be the best way to act considering my case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Resigning the root CA as a subordinate CA is indeed possible.

**Theoretically** you don't even need cooperation of the "offline root" and its private key. The new über-CA just emits a new certificate containing the ex-root's public key and name, and that's it; this information is public anyway (they are in the ex-root's certificate, which is public). However, in practice, the über-CA may prefer it if it receives a certificate request signed by the ex-root itself, thus using its private key.

Normally, you should be able to make such a request file with [certreq.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296456.aspx) (which should already be present on your machine). Use `certreq -new` with a policy file which contains the `KeyContainer` and `ProviderName` properties to point at your existing ex-root's private key. be sure to specify the exact same subject DN as the one used in the current ex-root's certificate: the condition for the new ex-root certificate to be acceptable as a substitute for the current one is that it uses the exact same DN and public key.

Once you have the certificate request, transport it to the über-CA, submit it, and use your administrative powers to authorize the issuing. This assumes that the über-CA accepts to produce sub-CA certificates, so you may have to edit and/or enable the relevant certificate template in that CA.

**Once this is done**, the new certificate exists, and clients may use it to validate certificates issued by the ex-root even if they trust only the über-CA. However, this works only if the said clients *see* the new sub-CA certificate. You can push it forcibly in the "intermediate CA" store on client machines. Alternatively, you may want to put it on a Web site referenced from the issued (end-entity) certificates themselves.

Indeed, any given certificate usually contains an `Authority Information Access` [standard extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.2.1) which includes an URL pointing to a place from which the issuing CA's certificate can be obtained. This is the basis for path building when the relevant intermediate CA certificates are not readily available. Chances are that your ex-root currently issues certificates with, as AIA, an URL pointing to its own self-signed certificate (on a Web site, in some LDAP server...). If you want clients to automatically obtain the new sub-CA certificate issued for the ex-root, then it should be sufficient to replace the ex-root self-signed certificate (wherever it is stored) with the new sub-CA certificate.

**Note** that the ex-root must still keep on with issuing CRL as per its policy.